# session timeout config with no web.xml file

Tags: java, spring, session-timeout

I just went xml-less with my spring 3.2 java app, I replaced all the config in web.xml with java config files, but I couldn't find the option to configure the session timeout.

Answer (score 1):

according to this [link](http://explodingjava.blogspot.jp/2010/05/servlet-30-annotations.html)
you will still need a web.xml to configure session timeout.

As also noted Programmatic configuration for session timeout does have an [open issue on the Servlet Spec JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-70) .